# GAE Static Resource Expiry

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, maven-gae-plugin

I have a pretty simple Java web app that follows the usual directory structure that Maven expects.

When I run the application locally ( `mvn -D skipTests clean package appengine:run` ) files which are requested from the `css` directory are given an expiry date of 10 minutes. Files from the `js` directory don't seem to be given an expiry date at all. Both of these directories are at the same level, directly beneath my webapp directory.

I don't believe that I have configured the css and js directories differently, so I would expect them both to get the default expiration of 10 minutes. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Without the relevant part of the pom.xml file it's hard to know what's going on. I would suggest to check this [section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#static_cache_expiration) of the docs where it explains how to set cache expiration parameters. Also it may be worth checking if the path wildcards are well configured.

Comment: @Happy-Monad : what details from the pom.xml would you need to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following is required in appengine.web.xml

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/**.js" expiration="10m" />
</static-files>
```